# How to update installed UWP .appxbundle with .appx

Tags: uwp, localization, windows-10-iot-core

I have developed an UWP app for windows iot core generated with bundle (always)

But now I'd like to add Romanian language and I read in this article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/401/localization-issues-when-using-app-bundle-in-uwp.html

because app doesn't work.

So I create a new version without bundle (never), but if I try to update by PackageManager I get an error and if I try by Windows Device Portal I get the same error.

Is there a way to update a bundle app with "unbundle" app?

Comment: Could you please describe the steps performed on the old version app in detail? Besides, I can’t understand well what “app doesn't work” means? What is your got behavior?

Comment: Hi @AryaDing-MSFT in old version of app generated with bundle setted as always, when user changes language, like Romanian, it returns texts in english (default lang)

Comment: Have you [create a configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn482043(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)  for the app package successfully with bundle(always)? Which targets on Windows Store 8.1 app, but it works for UWP app as well. Besides, you need to uninstall the old version when you install the new version, it prevents the new version from being affected .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunatelly, there is no such option. If you mean issues related to changing PrimaryLanguageOverride, now users will have access only to installed languages.

Good news is that users using Romanian version of Windows, or thoose who installed this language as an additional option will be ok when you'll add it to the app. All other machines will fallback to default language (en-US).

Comment: Hi @Oleg Mikhailov. In order to show Romanian language, I have to publish app with Bundle setted to "Never". So it will be installed all the resources, but then I can't update all the oldest version of installed apps because the new version is in conflict with the old. To solve it at the moment I use another supported cultur-info like "en-AU". I know that is not the best solution